# how can I pass curent_user from flask-security to a pluggable view function?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, graphql, flask-security, graphene-python

I have a flask app that uses flask security for authentication. I want to use graphql with [graphene](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/sqlalchemy/en/latest/tutorial/) to fetch data but I'm having trouble accessing the [current_user](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/848088a9fc6e8c9c418e8820e072cde6ac81dc00/flask_login/utils.py#L26) proxy which is I've always used to resolve requests. graphene only provides a customized [pluggable view](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/views/) which is understandable but it can't access the current_user within the context of the app and therefore current_user reverts back to AnonymousUser.

here is some sample code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemySessionUserDatastore, login_required, current_user, login_user

from flask_graphql import GraphQLView
import graphene
from graphene_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyConnectionField

from .models import UserModel, RoleModel, Todo, TodoModel
from .pipeline import session

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="../templates", static_folder="../static")
app.config.from_object('core.pipeline.configs.DevConfig')
user_datastore = SQLAlchemySessionUserDatastore(session, UserModel, RoleModel)
security = Security(app, user_datastore)

@app.route('/')
@login_required
def index(path):
    user = current_user

    return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: Are you using JWT for authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Main issue in your code is

> app.add_url_rule('/graphql', view_func=graphql_view())

Where graphql_view() run during code load without any flask request context.

Please, try this code

```
class GraphQLViewCurrentUser(GraphQLView):

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context.update({'current_user': current_user})
        return context


app.add_url_rule(
    '/graphql', view_func=GraphQLViewCurrentUser.as_view(
        'graphql', schema=schema, context={}, graphiql=True))
```